# Could not find module ‘Network.CGI’ It is a member of the hidden package ‘cgi-3001.3.0.2@cgi-3001.3.0.2-6aj81ZorTUo7RA61f0LJa8’

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying to use the `liftIO` function in the ghci repl.

`liftIO` appears to be defined in cgi's [Network.CGI module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cgi-3001.3.0.2/docs/Network-CGI.html#v:liftIO). I attempt to import that, entering `:m Network.CGI` or `import Network.CGI`, and get the following error

```
> :m Network.CGI

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Network.CGI’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘cgi-3001.3.0.2@cgi-3001.3.0.2-6aj81ZorTUo7RA61f0LJa8’.
Prelude Api.PesticideApplicationLog> import Network.CGI
```

**How do I import `liftIO` for use in ghci?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to import liftIO from the wrong module.

A [hoogle search](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=liftIO) for `liftIO` led me to Network.CGI, but the `liftIO` that I was looking for resides in [`Control.Monad.IO.Class`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html).

The import command

```
> :m Control.Monad.IO.Class
```

worked to import the appropriate `liftIO` for me.